How does a negative voltage surge waveform look?
I am trying to generate a surge pulse source in Xpedition AMS simulation tool. Attached is a +2kV-1.2/50us surge waveform I have currently generated. Now, I want to generate a -2kV waveform with same timing characteristics (1.2/50us). So, will the negative surge be a vertical mirror image of the positive waveform or is there any other way to represent a negative voltage surge ?

I have also tried to generate a -1kV surge as follows. Please review if this is the correct way to represent a negative surge. It is important to get the waveform correct to test our protection circuits in simulation.


Multiple (5) surge pulses are generated to suffice application requirements.

These have mirrored behavior, stemming from the logic that the surge-causing malfunction (e.g. lightning) could affect each of the mains lines predominantly, so the differential could be negative or positive but will have the same typical time domain shape. Also consider that the post surge voltage might not be zero, but could still be peak mains voltage

That is correct. The same generator network is used, it is simply connected in reverse polarity to the coupling network.  The generator is isolated from ground and can be connected freely in any orientation.

Understood, thank you for your response !
